# OpenGL EGL returns 0x300c (EGL_BAD_PARAMETER) at eglGetDisplay in docker

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu, opengl, egl

I am trying to run a simple example to set up EGL context in a docker container. However, I keep getting this error message :

```
Detected 0 devices
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  EGL error 0x300c at eglGetDisplay
Aborted
```

Basically, `eglQueryDevicesEXT` returns 0, and `eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT` returns error code `0x300c (EGL_BAD_PARAMETER)` .

I have tried on :

1. Ubuntu 16.04 docker on a Macbook Pro
2. Ubuntu 16.04 docker on a Ubuntu 16.04 server with Nvidia GPU

On these docker environments, I installed `openGL` and `ELG` using `apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev` and `apt-get install libegl1-mesa-dev`. CMake can find the components `GL::GL` and `EGL::EGL`.

I have tried link to `libEGL.so` both manually and using `find_package` in CMake.

This is driving me crazy! I can't figure out why EGL can't detect devices? How can I resolve this error?

Here is my full code. I have also tried `EGLDisplay eglDpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);`  which gives me the same error. Thanks!

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h>


void assertEGLError(const std::string& msg) {
    EGLint error = eglGetError();

    if (error != EGL_SUCCESS) {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "EGL error 0x" << std::hex << error << " at " << msg;
        throw std::runtime_error(s.str());
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // 1. Initialize EGL
//    EGLDisplay eglDpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    int deviceID = 0;  // TODO hardcode

    EGLDisplay eglDpy;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLContext context;
    EGLint num_config;

    static const int MAX_DEVICES = 16;
    EGLDeviceEXT eglDevs[MAX_DEVICES];
    EGLint numDevices;

    PFNEGLQUERYDEVICESEXTPROC eglQueryDevicesEXT =
            (PFNEGLQUERYDEVICESEXTPROC)eglGetProcAddress("eglQueryDevicesEXT");

    eglQueryDevicesEXT(MAX_DEVICES, eglDevs, &numDevices);
    printf("Detected %d devices\n", numDevices);
    PFNEGLGETPLATFORMDISPLAYEXTPROC eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT =
            (PFNEGLGETPLATFORMDISPLAYEXTPROC)eglGetProcAddress("eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT");

    // Choose device by deviceID
    eglDpy = eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT(EGL_PLATFORM_DEVICE_EXT, eglDevs[deviceID], nullptr);

    assertEGLError("eglGetDisplay");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG I finally solved this problem. Turned out I was linking to the wrong library on the server.

I found the answer in this post: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-opengl-visualization-without-an-x-server/73204/15

The key is to link to the libraries in `/usr/lib/nvidia-410/`, not the system default `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so`

The new `CMake` that works:

```
target_link_libraries(sandbox PRIVATE /usr/lib/nvidia-410/libEGL.so)
target_link_libraries(sandbox PRIVATE /usr/lib/nvidia-410/libGLX.so)
target_link_libraries(sandbox PRIVATE /usr/lib/nvidia-410/libOpenGL.so)
```

Previously I used CMake's `findOpenGL` to search for link libraries, which **does not work**

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGL EGL GLX)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
if(OPENGL_FOUND)
   message("Found OpenGL in the current environment!")
else()
   message("Error: No OpenGL found.")
endif()

message("OpenGL include dirs" )
message("${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("EGL include dirs" )
message("${OPENGL_EGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if (OpenGL_EGL_FOUND)
   message("EGL Found!")
else()
   message("EGL Not Found!")
endif()

message(${OPENGL_egl_LIBRARY})
message(${OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY})
message(${OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY}
```

Note again **this does not work !!**

```
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
```